# How can I restart RDS aurora cluster with 0 downtime?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am using RDS Aurora Postgresql 11.9 and I need to modify a static parmaeter in the parameter group. AWS says modifying a static parameter requires rebooting db instance. I have three instances in the cluster and one of them is write. I am looking for a solution to reboot the database without any downtime.

- Deploy my application to use the write instance for read/write requests which make the 2 read instances idle.
- Reboot the two read instances
- Failover the write instance to make one of the read as primary db instance
- Then reboot the old write instance

If I follow the above instruction, is it possible to achieve 0 downtime?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. There will be a downtime in the failover phase

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not downtime is a desirable thing during a DB cutover. Having two replicas writeable at the same time nearly guarantees a split brain state that requires lengthy manual recovery, so in order to perform a clean handoff it's necessary to have some window in which neither replica is writeable in order to ensure an atomic swap. Not postgres, but this is quite a good article on how to minimize downtime when performing maintenance operations: https://www.wise.jobs/2022/01/17/how-wise-reduced-aws-rds-maintenance-downtimes-from-10-minutes-to-100-milliseconds/